# equation for a line in 3D, but with shifted origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

The (unit) direction vector $r$ of a line $L$ in 3D I write in spherical coordinates,

$$
r_x = \sin\theta\cos\phi \\
r_y = \sin\theta\sin\phi \\
r_z = \cos\theta
$$
This line passes through the point $(0, 0, 0)$, and I can write it as $L(t) = rt$, where $t$ is my parameter. What I am interested in is a line with the same gradient as above, but now I want it to pass through the point $P=(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ instead of $(0,0,0)$.

I am unsure of how to generalize $L(t)$ in order to achieve this, but here is my suggestion: I believe it is sufficient simply to shift all coordinates, i.e. now I can write $L(t) = P + rt$. But I also believe that this requires for me to normalize $P$ since $r$ is also normalized. Is this suggestion correct?

Comment: Your hunch is correct. I don't see why need to normalize anything.

Comment: @Kaster Thanks. Say $P$ is $(1, 2, 3)$, where these values are in units of meters. Then $r$ needs to be in units of meters as well. But currently $r$ is unitless. That is why I think I need to normalize $P$, but you are saying that I am wrong about this?

Comment: If you work with units, you need to reduce everything to same system of units as well. For example, $L$ - in meters and $t$ is time say in seconds. Then $r$ should be in $m/s$. If $P$ is also in meters then you don't have to do anything. If $P$ in kilometers, definitely you need to reduce it to meters first.

Comment: @Kaster Thanks. Can you convert the first comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you introduce new system of coordinates shifted by $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, then in new system the line equation is still
$$
L'(t) = rt
$$
so, to write that equation in old system you just need to do backward translation
$$
L(t) = P + L'(t) = (x_0, y_0, z_0) + rt
$$
You have to keep in mind, that angles $(\theta, \phi)$ are constants, and the only free parameter is $t$. Otherwise you'll get an equation of unit sphere, so with presence of $t$, you'll get a family of concentric spheres.

Comment: You meant: "so, to write that equation in **old** system [...]", but a good answer

Comment: @BillyJean yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.